# Why does using JWT refresh tokens protect against CSRF during authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, jwt, csrf

I have read a few articles regarding JWT refresh tokens, and how/why they are used. One thing i have seen mentioned here: https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/#persistance and here: https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id

is that using refresh tokens mitigates against CSRF attacks. The first article states:

> The refresh token is sent by the auth server to the client as an HttpOnly cookie and is automatically sent by the browser in a /refresh_token API call.
> Because client side Javascript can't read or steal an HttpOnly cookie, this is a little better at mitigating XSS than persisting it as a normal cookie or in localstorage.
> This approach is also safe from CSRF attacks, because even though a form submit attack can make a /refresh_token API call, the attacker cannot get the new JWT token value that is returned.

The second article says something similar:

> Although a form submit to `/refresh_token` will work and a new access token will be returned, the attacker can't read the response if they're using an HTML form

I am struggling to see how this would prevent CSRF attacks as I am thinking the following:

1. A request to `/refresh token` from another domain to the users will return new JWT token to the user. I am going to assume this is stored in a HttpOnly cookie (as is done in the first article)
2. As CSRF does not involve any injection of javascript and the cookie it httpOnly, the attacker can't read the value of the new JWT token.
3. However, if the JWT token is stored in a cookie again, surely a CSRF attacker can just send another request using this new cookie, with the new JWT token sinde?

If my understanding is correct, I am struggling to see how CSRF attacks are prevented by using refresh tokens. **Can someone please explain exactly why refresh tokens prevent CSRF attacks, and why the CSRF attacker can't just use the new JWT the user would receive for future attacks?**

It seems to me that the thing that would actually be preventing a CSRF attack would be the use of a sameSite cookie, or maybe using some sort of anti-forgery token.

Comment: _"However, if the JWT token is stored in a cookie again, surely a CSRF attacker can just send another request using this new cookie, with the new JWT token sinde?"_ - you're not supposed to read JWT's from cookies on the server side. Client needs to read the cookie and put the JWT in Authorization header. And to do that, it needs access to the cookie.

Comment: The thing is that although the refresh-token can be sent via the CSRF call, but the attacker cannot read the resulting JWT token for his further attacks. Consider the attacker posts an HTML form => then how he gonna read the result? Consider the attacker deployed an AJAX request => then the CORS policy of your site prevents him to make such call. See? Either way he cannot read the resulting JWT token.

Answer (score 1):

The new jwt would not be returned from the identity provider as a cookie. That would not make much sense as the client on a different origin would not be able to read it. Instead, the token is passed in the response body, or even the url (usually not the token in that case, but let's not delve into that).

So the idp has its httpOnly cookie to authenticate the user, issues a new token in some way that is not a cookie, and the client stores the token for the appropriate origin (not the idp) in say localstorage. This way, any call to the resource server is not vulnerable to csrf, because the token needs to be explicitly be added from localstorage. The idp can be called by attacker.com to issue a new token ("csrf"), but attacker.com will not have access to the token due to the same origin policy, so it's not exploitable.

Note that even if the new token is returned as a cookie for the idp and read from there by the client, it's still ok, because the idp will do nothing with that token, and the resource server (~api) will not receive it automatically.